# Input almacena datos viejos

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Tengo un input tipo `number`, despendiendo de un `radiobutton` este input puede cambiar entre tipo `date` y tipo `number`. El problema es que despues del `submit` y cambiando de selección del `radiobutton` mi input almacena datos viejos del tipo date o en el peor de los casos marca 2 veces el mismo dato

Mi vista

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form_transferencias_enviadas">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Parámetro de impresión</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="parametro_impresion" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" id="hasta_hidden" hidden>
        <span>Hasta:</span>
        <input type="date" id="parametro_impresion_hasta">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2" id="select_hidden" hidden>
        <select id="slc_transferencia_destino" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
          @foreach($empresas as $empresa)
            @if($empresa->nombre!=Auth::user()->activo()->pluck('nombre')->first())
               <option value="{{$empresa->nombre}}">{{$empresa->nombre}}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Mi js

```js
//ocultar campos
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="busqueda_radio"]').on('ifClicked', function(event) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value)
    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('type', 'number').val('').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
      case 2:
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('type', 'date').val('').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
      case 3:
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
    }
  })
})


function por_numero(numero_transferencia) {
  console.log(numero_transferencia)
}

function por_fecha(desde, hasta) {
  console.log(desde + ' hasta ' + hasta)
}

function por_destino(destino) {
  console.log(destino)
}

function submit_buton(caso) {
  $('#form_transferencias_enviadas').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    switch (caso) {
      case 1:
        por_numero($('#parametro_impresion').val())
        break
      case 2:
        por_fecha($('#parametro_impresion').val(), $('#parametro_impresion_hasta').val())
        break
      case 3:
        por_destino($('#slc_transferencia_destino').val())
        break

    }
  })
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

A la hora de realizar el cambio con el radio button deberías limpiar el campo de texto donde introducís el valor. De esa forma no debería arrastrarte ningún valor anterior.

```
//ocultar campos
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="busqueda_radio"]').on('ifClicked', function(event) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value)
    document.getElementById("parametro_impresion").value = ""//o la forma que prefieras usar.
```

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se resuelve limpiando el submit y asi evitar que se cree una nueva instancia del mismo

```
$('#form_transferencias_enviadas').off('submit').submit(function (e) {})
```